# Is this short proof ambiguous? Prove $\partial \partial S \subset \partial S.$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

Would you consider this proof to be ambiguous and, therefore, insufficient?

Note: $\partial S$ is the set of boundary points of a subset $S \subset M$ of some metric $M.$

Prove $\partial \partial S \subset \partial S.$

Consider any point $p \in \partial \partial S.$ All neighborhoods $N_rp$ of $p$ contain points in $\partial S$ and points in $(\partial S)^c.$ Suppose $p \not\in \partial S,$ that is, $p \in (\partial S)^c.$ Then, there is some neighborhood $N_{r'}p$ that contains no points in $\partial S,$ namely the neighborhood $N_{r'}p$ where $r' < d(p,p')$ for the nearest point $p' \in \partial S$ to $p,$ contradicting the initial assumption. Hence, $p \in \partial S.$

Comment: How are you certain there is a nearest point "$p'$"?

Comment: Well, I am assuming that $\partial S$ is not empty and that the distance is not infinite. Does it not follow immediately?

Comment: Sorry, I read too much into this. With a metric you are immediately a Haussdorf  space, so such a point exists.

Comment: Haha, I don't know what a Haussdorf space is. I'm learning topology as a section in a real analysis class.

Comment: I understand. This proof looks good to me.

Comment: You have the right idea but you can't claim a nearest point.  You have to do a bit of finese and for a point p find a radius small enough it can't go to either the edge of the original neighborhood nor back to the original point.  It'll take a teensy bit of correct wording but the final proof will be equally short.

Comment: Thanks, fleablood!

Comment: An alternative proof could be based on fact 1: "for all $A\subseteq X$, $A$ is closed iff $\partial A \subseteq A$" plus  fact 2: "$\partial A$ is a closed set for all $A$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you can argue equally shortly using the definition of boundary in a topological space $X$: $x \in \partial E$ if and only if every neighborhood contains a point of $E$ and a point of $X \setminus E$.

If $x \in \partial \partial S$ and $U$ is a neighborhood of $x$, then $U$ contains a point $y \in \partial S$. Since $U$ is a neighborhood of $y$, $U$ contains a point of $S$ and a point of $X \setminus S$. It follows $x \in \partial S$.

Comment: This works if $U$ is an *open* neighbourhood, which is enough. So in a metric space the OP should know that $B(x,r)$ is such an open neighbourhood.

Comment: Would you say U is a neighborhood of y in the sense that U contains a neighborhood of y, namely the neighborhood with the radius that is the difference between that of U and the distance between x and y?

Answer (score 0):

Exercise.  Prove
$\partial \partial A = \partial A -$interior $\partial A.$